# How to create a Chinese Sentiment Annotator of Stanford Core NLP

Tags: stanford-nlp

Stanford Core NLP software has an annotator of sentiment , but it only supports for English , I want to create an sentiment annotator for Chinese . What should I do ? Can someone give me some advice on it , thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, we do not have any trained model for Chinese sentiment analysis. To train a Chinese model, you'd need to construct a sentiment treebank similar to the [Stanford Sentiment Treebank](http://nlp.stanford.edu/sentiment/treebank.html) and then retrain the sentiment model, but this is not a small task.